# Year/Month based Post Archive List With Entity Framework

Tags: sql, view, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, viewbag

I want to make a simple Blog Post Archive List like below

2014

- January (1)

2013

- December (1)
- November (14) -> Link to search with date
- October (3)
- May (5)
- April (3)

I need to send this via ViewBag.Archives. When I perform below SQL in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
select year(Created) as PostYear, datename(month,Created) as PostMonth,count(ID) as ArticleAmount from Post group by year(Created), datename(MONTH,Created) order by PostYear, PostMonth
```

I get:

```
PostYear    PostMonth   ArticleAmount
2010        February    1
2011        September   1
2012        April       1
2012        February    1
2013        February    4
2013        March       1
2014        February    1
```

My Code:

```
ViewBag.Archives = db.Posts
.GroupBy(group => new { group.Created.Year, group.Created.Month })
.Select(x => new { count = x.Count(), Year = x.Key.Year, Month = x.Key.Month });
```

My View:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Archives)
{
    <p>@item.Year</p>
}
```

ERROR: Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Year'

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
ViewBag.Archives = db.Posts
            .GroupBy(group => new {group.Created.Year, group.Created.Month})
            .Take(5)
            .Select(x => new GuestBookPost()
            {
                count = x.Count,
                Year = x.Key.Created.Year,
                Month = x.Key.Created.Month
            }).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

- Use the ToList() on the select :).
- Try using an object or a model to store the data in, this will also make is easier to add month names as accessing in the view. Example below, replaced "ObjectName()", with "PostGroup":

`public class GuestbookPost {

    public int Count { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

}`

PS: Sorry for the bad formatting, still learning :)